# add quotes to tweets grabbed by json

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, quotes, html

Using Seaofcloud's Tweet jQuery plugin to inject a recent tweet into a site. Wondering how I can add some quotes around the incoming tweet. It's fetched via JSON

Here's a jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/mrgta/2/

my guess is that it's in the commented out section, specifically this chunk below

```
 var text = '<span class="tweet_text">'+$([tweet_text]).makeHeart().capAwesome().capEpic()[0]+ '</span>';
```

Not my area of expertise.. I guessed (and hoped) that `&quot;` wrapped around it would work... HA.

Ideas? thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure I understand this question correctly, but it is exactly what you wrote: Just change it to var text = '<span class="tweet_text">&quot;'+$([tweet_text]).makeHeart().capAwesome().capEpic()[0]+ '&quot;</span>';

Comment: @data That's what I originally tried, but it breaks the code and doesn't return a tweet. any other ideas?

Comment: @data Confirmed, your modification causes the jsFiddle to provide the desired behavior. Please post your comment as an answer.
@technopeasant I am trying your jsFiddle with data's update and successfully pulling 4 quoted tweets back.

Comment: @arcain - can you save and share your jsfiddle? Here's the version Ive got with Data's modification and no success: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/mrgta/3/

Comment: Sure, here you go. I forked this off of yours: http://jsfiddle.net/RZjrc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly,

```
var text = '<span class="tweet_text">\"'+$([tweet_text]).makeHeart().capAwesome().capEpic()[0]+ '\"</span>'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mrgta/5/

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the comments, all you need to do is what you already suggested

http://jsfiddle.net/eRQWK/

```
var text = '<span class="tweet_text">&bdquo;'+$([tweet_text]).makeHeart().capAwesome().capEpic()[0]+ '&rdquo;</span>';
```

This even gives you the better looking lower and upper quotes.